# C++: Initialization within switch case is not consistently giving out error

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I read that initialization within cases of switch is supposed to give compiler error.
But when I tried two different version. One is not giving out the error (Ex1), I can't understand why.

Ex 1:

```
switch (i)
{
case 1:
    int k;
    break;
case 2:
    int j=3;
    break;
}
```

Ex2:

```
switch (i)
{
case 1:
    int k=3;
    break;
case 2:
    int j;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a switch block, every declaration that comes before a `case` is available at that `case`. The error occurs when there is a `case` to which the `switch` can jump to which is located after the initialization of a variable that you could access there. If that `case` was jumped to, you could use the variable despite its initialization never occuring.

In the first example, there is no `case` which would skip an initialization. The only initialization is `int j=3;` which comes after every `case` so it can't be skipped. `k` is not initialized so its initialization can't be skipped.

In the second example,if `i == 2` then `k`'s initialization would be skipped.

One solution is to define a scope for each case. Then, the variables defined for a `case` is only accessible from that `case` and the problem can't occur. For example :

```
void foo(int i)
{
    switch (i)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        int k=3;
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        // k is not accessible here
        int j;
        break;
    }
    }
}
```